# Doing Date Comparisons w/ {yr, mo, day} Dates

Tags: date-and-time

I'm working with dates in the form, e.g.,

```
t1 = {2017,4,17}    and    
t2 = {2017,4,3}.
```

I want to execute commands like

```
If[t1 == t2, Print["Right!"], Print["Wrong!"]];
```

This works, but, the following doesn't.

```
If[t1 >= t2, Print["Right!"], Print["Wrong!"]];
```

What "comparison commands" can I use to achieve common <=, < , >, >=, and != functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare lists directly, unless they are equal, or you will get the expression unevaluated.

You can use the build in `DateObject` for such comparison.

```
DateObject[{2017, 4, 17}] > DateObject[{2017, 4, 3}]
(*True*)
```

Please read the documentation for more usages.