# Dates and LessEqual (<=)

Tags: date-and-time

The following does not return anything (Mathematica 11). I was expecting that "true" would be printed.

```
If[{2016, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0.`} <= {2016, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0.`},
  Print["true"];,
  Print["false"];];
```

Why is there no result?

Comment: I saw the same question a few days ago. [141016](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141016/doing-date-comparisons-w-yr-mo-day-dates/141017#141017)